# Linker error when using boost threads

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I'm trying to use the boost threads, but when running the program i get this:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_46.lib'
```

The directories I've included in the linker, are: c:\boost_1_46_0\libs\ and c:\boost_1_46_0\boost.
And I am using Visual Studio Express 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: i'd expect to see that error when you compile (and then link) the program? Have you checked the directories for the lib file?

Comment: i have only libs directory (no lib) as I see

Comment: @Jimmy  good point!  The question must be wrong, this is an error message from the linker, NOT from running the program

Comment: Yes it seems that way, but when compiling i get this: ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== only when i run the program it gives me the error

Comment: do have a ".libs" file with the same root as the file specified? Out of interest, have you built the boost libraries for your platform?

Comment: @vBx You have some serious configuration problems!

Comment: Yes ive build them, it worked with eclipse/Mingw but here in visual studio it doesnt.

Comment: Remove your boost installation.  Use the boost windows installer.  Do not try to build boost libraries yourself, it is  somewhat challenging.

Comment: I used bjam.exe....dont know if that is ok

Comment: did you build them with MinGW or msvc?

Comment: Here is the windows installer http://www.boostpro.com/download/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify $(BOOSTROOT)/lib as 'additional library directory' for the linker.  ( Note: it is NOT libs with an s )

This assumes that you have built the boost libraries using the visual studio compiler.  From the discussion in the comments, it seems you have not done this.

I recomend, instead of trying to build the libraries yourself, you use the installer to get pre-built binaries.  Here is the installer: http://www.boostpro.com/download/

Comment: @vBx  Then you must have a very strange install of boost.  I recomend removing your boost installation and starting again.

Comment: Maybe you are refering to this: c:\boost_1_46_0\stage\lib\ ? It contains lots of .a and .dll files. Ive include this too but still getting the same error.

Comment: Yes i didnt build using visul studio, ok i will install using the link you gave me, thank you very much